# How to specify foreign relations with Embedded Entity

Tags: android, android-room

Given answer changed the embedded type to a foreign key type, I'm not looking for this.

I've a student table and an embedded type address.

**Student Schema**

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | address_id |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | John |          1 |
|  2 | Jane |          2 |
+----+------+------------+
```

**Address Schema**

```
+----+------------------+
| id |     addressLine  |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | 123 Acme Street  |
|  2 | 456 Beach Street |
+----+------------------+
```

---

**Student Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student(
     @PrimaryKey var id: Long, 
     var name: String?, 
     @Embedded var address: Address // can't change, given answer changed it
)
```

**Address Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "address")
data class Address(
     @PrimaryKey var id: Long, 
     val addressLine: String
)
```

**DAO Interface**

```
@Dao
interface StudentDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = :id INNER JOIN address ON student.address_id = address.id")
    fun findById(id: Long): Student
}
```

Issue: Current unable to populate the Embedded address of the Student.

Answer (score 1):

Common way for your use-case is to use additional POJO class (not an entity) for getting joined result from both tables.

So, entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student(
     @PrimaryKey var id: Long, 
     var name: String?, 
     var address_id: Long // <- you can make it foreign key in addition 
)

@Entity(tableName = "address")
data class Address(
     @PrimaryKey var id: Long, 
     val addressLine: String
)
```

and auxiliary POJO class:

```
data class StudentWithAdress( // <-- you can change the class name to more descriptive one 
     @Embedded var student: Student 
     @Embedded var address: Address 
)
```

Your dao then:

```
@Dao
interface StudentDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = :id INNER JOIN address ON student.address_id = address.id")
    fun findById(id: Long): StudentWithAdress
}
```

**UPDATED**

**Second way** is to use [one-to-one Room's @Relation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-one) instead using SQLite Joins

This method uses the **same** entities, but query and auxiliary class differ a little bit:

```
data class StudentWithAdress(
     @Embedded var student: Student 
     @Relation(
         parentColumn = "addressId",
         entityColumn = "id"
    )
    var address: Address 
)
```

and query would be simpler:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = :id")
    fun findById(id: Long): StudentWithAdress
}
```

**Conclusion**

1. `Student` class should include **ONLY** `addressId` (not whole `Address` object), and you use separate class `StudentWithAdress` that has both `Student` and `Address`. So to insert value to `Student` you should insert there `addressId` from corresponding `Address` table. That is common and correct way.
2. Both described ways are similar, you could choose any. Personally I prefer the Relations-way.
3. Technically it's possible to use just two entities without auxiliary class (and hold all the `Address` content inside `Stident` entity), but I think it breaks principle of relational table's normalisation and I don't want to include this in my answer since it's anti-pattern.

**UPDATED 2 (anti-pattern)**

I don't recommend it, but if you insist you can use next schema:

```
@Entity(tableName = "address")
data class Address(
     @PrimaryKey var idAddress: Long,  // <-- changed
     val addressLine: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student(
     @PrimaryKey var id: Long, 
     var name: String?, 
     @Embedded var address: Address 
)
```

How it works? @Embedded means that in fact Sqlite table `Student` includes all the fields of `Address`. In your case in actual Sqlite table there will be 4 columns - id, name, idAddress, addressLine (that's why it's necessary to change `Address` primary key's name, since there can't be fields with the same name).
Room hides this a little bit and you work with the `Student` object via `address` field. Why this is bad? Let's look at scenario:

1. You save `Address` with id = 1, addressLine = "Some address #1".
2. You set this address in some `Student` object and persist it. Under the hood Sqlite in `Student` table will hold values `id = 1`, `addressLine = Some address #1`.
3. Then on some reason you change `addressLine` in `Address` to "Some address #2".
4. But in `Student` table there is still old value of `addressLine`. That's a bug. Or you should persist this change at the `Student` table, and that's bad as well.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, can you please also edit and add the one-to-one version, that's what i was looking for

Comment: this has to be whole Address object, not this -> `var address_id: Long // <- you can make it foreign key in addition`

Comment: Updated my answer. As for `this has to be whole Address object, not this` I think it's wrong way, I tried to explain that in Conclusion-section of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reattempting, I appreciate. I'm actually looking for a solution without auxiliary class, flatten student data at the root level, and Address as embedded. Can you please do one more attempt and you can label it as anti-pattern.

Comment: To iterate, I've only two classes here, Student and Address. `data class Student(
     @PrimaryKey var id: Long, 
     var name: String?, 
     @Embedded var address: Address
)`

Comment: Updated with one more attempt )

Comment: Awesome. one more thing, I want to see the @Query for the DAO for this anti-pattern. Thanks again.

Comment: oh, `@Embedded means that in fact Sqlite table Student includes all the fields of Address`, I was under the impression that the tables will be separate. so no way for me to use Room, I could do this easily with direct sqlite apis :(

Comment: I can't share your disappointment ) There is no magic in Room, it's just a useful Sqlite wrapper. But It helps to use Sqlite with less code and to get ready objects as a result instead of raw Cursor. I think common way I've described is convenient enough. Still it's your decision to use what you think suitable for you. By the way, Embedded annotation usually is used for POJO, not for entities.